# What is wrong with the formatting of this answer?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow

The second half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373/what-c-pitfalls-should-i-avoid/293047#293047) is missing when viewing the question (Chrome 5, IE 8, and FF 3.6).  In Chrome, it also looks like a code-formatting tag is not closed properly.

The answer looks alright in the edit-preview and I didn't see anything out of the ordinary in the markdown.

Any thoughts?

(sorry if this has been asked or answered before; I did a search but couldn't find anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sometimes happens on old posts; the solution is to do a (noop) edit to force re-rendering of the Markdown. I just did that, and now it looks fine.

Comment: Now I know, and knowing is half the battle.  Thanks, balpha!